# What format specifier should I use here?

Tags: c, file, types, char, format-specifiers

Got this code right here to print out the name of an opened file (its a height map in case you were wondering) and every time I try to print out I get format warnings, which format specifier should I use for this?

```
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("textures/height.png", &width, &height, &nr_components, 0);
    printf("Loaded file: %u\n", data);
```

Comment: To be clear I'm just asking for the format specifier

Comment: Do you want the format specifier for `unsigned char` or `unsigned char*`?

Comment: `data` is defined as a pointer to an `unsigned char` presumably it holds the address of the first element of an array of `unsigned char`

Comment: ```unsigned char*```

Comment: Are you trying to print just one character, or the numeric code of that character, or the entire string?

Comment: `stbi_load` doesn't return a string. It returns bitmap data. You can't print it like a string. The name of the file is presumably `textures/height.png`.

Comment: Re "*not errors but still*", No, definitely an error, even if your compiler proceeded.

Comment: @Chillzy, improve your question, for others, by including the exact warning rather than just "I get format warnings,".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is to print the address where the data was loaded, that would be `%p`:

```
printf("Loaded file: %p\n", (void*)data);
```

If you want to print the actual data, byte by byte, you should loop over the bytes and use `%hhu` (for decimal) or `%hhx` (for hexadecimal):

```
printf("Loaded file:\n");
for(int i = 0; i < width*height*nr_components; ++i)
    printf("%hhx ", data[i]);
printf("\n");
```

`data` doesn't contain the name of the file though, so if you want to print just the name, then print that same string that you passed to `stbi_load`:

```
const char *filename = "textures/height.png";
unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &nr_components, 0);
printf("Loaded file: %s\n", filename);
```

Comment: Minor: to better handle large files, use `size_t`: `size_t n = (size_t)width*height*nr_components; for(size_t i = 0; i <n; ++i)`